# ¿Cómo puedo modificar un texto insertado en un JTextArea?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo el siguiente texto escrito en el JTextArea:

```
Titulo: Las computadoras

Nombre: Juan Perez

Curso: 8vo

Fecha: 2018/01/01
```

Ahora yo quiero modificar el Nombre: Juan Perez, como puede cambiar el texto Juan Perez por Juanito Alzar.

He intentado con el siguiente método pero se adjunta al inicio: Juanito AlzarJuan Perez, entonces quiero que solo se escriba el nuevo texto.

```
//Nombre:
buscarD("e: ");

public int buscarD(String menbrete) {

    String todoTexto = jTextArea1.getText();

    int posicion = todoTexto.indexOf(menbrete);

    return posicion + 3; //retirna la posicion a adjuntar Nombre: 

}


public void editarItem(String itemTxt, String nuevoItem) {

    int posicion = buscarD(itemTxt);

    String texto = datosCliente[1];

    jTextArea1.insert(nuevoItem, posicion);

}
```

Comment: Seria mas fácil que uses Programación orientada a objetos. Creas tu clase, modificas el atributo que deseas, sobrescribes el toString dándole el formato que quieres y luego llenas el TextArea

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la solución:

```
jTextAreaX.replaceRange(nuevoItem, posicion, posicion+viejoItem);
```

Comment: Tu respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad, por favor siempre redacta tus respuestas basandote en [answer]

Answer (score 0):

para cambiar o obtener un datos de un jtextarea tiene que utilizar la siguiente funcion:

```
    //cambiar el datos de un jtextarea
    jTextArea1.setText("juanito perez");

    //obtener el dato de un jtextarea
    String nombre=jTextArea1.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

El método adecuado para modificar un texto insertado en un `JTextArea` es:

- `void    replaceRange​(String str, int start, int end)`

*El cual Reemplaza el texto de la posición indicada de inicio a fin con el nuevo texto especificado.*

---

**Ej:** En tu caso para conseguir lo que estás intentado bastaría con hacer esto..

```
  String todoTexto = textArea.getText();
  int inicio = todoTexto.indexOf("Juan");
  textArea.replaceRange("Juanito Alzar", inicio, inicio+10);
```

**Resultado:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para reemplazar cualquier palabra, lo podremos hacer de esta manera
`String todoTexto = textArea.getText();
        String textoAReemplazar = "Juan Perez";
        int inicio = todoTexto.indexOf("Juan");
        int fin = inicio + textoAReemplazar.length();
        textArea.replaceRange("Juanito Alzar", inicio, fin);` 
Indicando el texto a reemplazar por el adecuado. Saludos!